# Imposing linear restrictions with MARSS

Tags: r, state-space

On the [MARSS Userguide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/UserGuide.pdf) it is said that you can impose linear restrictions on parameters and they give a theoretical example.

I'd like a practical example. My problem is that I do not know how to implement a linear restriction such as:

```
a   b
c  2*a
```

Should I use a "2*a" string ? won't that be considered the name of the coefficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of any theoretical examples in our User's Guide, but `MARSS` will interpret the string `"2*a"` as 2 times the parameter `a`.

Comment: You're sure? From experimentation it seemed the other way round

Comment: @PedroBraz Sorry, but I misinterpreted your Q the first time, so I edited my answer.

Comment: No worries. Appreciate it.